# Trying to get scrollerProperties in PySide2 causes crash

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I have recently been working on a GUI that will be run on a touch screen in PySide2, and I wanted to implement scrolling by flicking on the touch screen. From what I could tell, the best way to do this would be to use a QScroller. I tried to implement it with this, but I did not like how the scroller would allow horizontal scrolling even though I had disabled the horizontal scroll bar. I saw online that it should be possible to disable this by modifying the scrollerProperties. However, whenever I try to get or set the scroller properties, the entire program immediately crashes. I have the following example, which reproduces my issue:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QSize, QPoint, Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QScrollArea, QScroller


class ScrollerCrash(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, None)
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self._window = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._window)
        self.labels = []

        self.panel = QWidget(self)
        self.panel.resize(QSize(500, 10000))
        for i in range(0, 100):
            label = QLabel(self.panel)
            label.setText(f'Label {i}')
            label.resize(QSize(500, 100))
            label.move(QPoint(0, i * 100))
            label.show()
            self.labels.append(label)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setEnabled(False)
        self.scroll_area.resize(QSize(500, 500))
        self.scroll_area.show()
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.panel)

        self.scroller = QScroller(self.scroll_area)
        self.scroller.grabGesture(self.scroll_area, QScroller.TouchGesture)
        self.scroller.grabGesture(self.scroll_area, QScroller.LeftMouseButtonGesture)
        print('before getting properties')
        self.props = self.scroller.scrollerProperties()  # Causes a seg fault
        print('after getting properties')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QApplication()
    test = ScrollerCrash()
    test.show()
    application.exec_()
```

My PySide2 version is 5.15.10.

I can't figure out any way to work around this. Is there something I am missing, or is there a better way to go about what I am doing? Thanks!

Comment: did you run in console/terminal to see error message?

Comment: I've not used QScroller a lot, so I'm not sure if there's a *real* way to completely prevent scrolling for a specific orientation. Nonetheless, a solution would be to do `self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(0)))`. Note that your code has a few issues; 1. even if you *are* using a central widget, the scroll area isn't its child, and while it's possible to have "free children" of a QMainWindow, that should **always** be done with care and awareness; 2. you should use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: Also note that, according to the docs, QScroller cannot be directly instantiated, and you should use the static `QScroller.scroller(widget)` instead.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the downside of having "free children" of a QMainWindow? What is the better way to add my widgets?

Comment: @reed53 Well, for starters, the [QMainWindow documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) itself explicitly says that "Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder". Ignoring that aspect may result in unexpected behavior, as some styles *assume* (as the documentation implies) that a central widget *has* to exist, in order to properly lay out and display dynamic widgets such as docks and toolbars. As long as a central widget is set, using "free widgets" is not wrong per se.

Comment: @reed53 Still, there can be some issues, for instance when dealing with widget stacking order (widgets overlying others, like the menubar or statusbar partially hidden because a "child" widget is being displayed above it) or focus management (that can become visually inconsistent for widgets that are not properly realigned when the window is resized). QMainWindow has its own private layout management (used to set geometries of its main components like the menu bar, dock widgets, etc.), it's mostly inaccessible and unusable from the public API, but it has to be considered nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante), it was as simple as using QScroller.scroller() instead of directly creating a QScroller. I somehow missed that when I was going over the documentation.